# Use an external HDD as normal (secondary) HDD?

Tags: external-hard-drive

Is it ok to use external HDD connected via USB as normal HDD that means for daily normal work or it will fast lead to destruction of the external HDD? It would be used as secondary HDD that means only to work with some specific data (website development).

Answer (score 2):

Well, you will need the following:

- Enclosure
- The HDD (depending on the amount of time you are thinking of having this on
- The system should already see the drive when it is connected and mount it without any issues. There is no need for any special setup
  in bios as a secondary HDD.
- An outlet to power your enclosure with any required controller built    in.
- Remember the enclosure will have to be designed to work with the port    (USB 2/3, Firewire, Esata, Thunderbolt, etc). Always buy name
  brand enclosure and parts. This "cheaper OEM parts error" cost me an 
  expensive gaming computer.

I learned my lesson and just use prebuilt Western Digital and Seagate external Hard Disk Drives now.

There are specific drives for always-on NAS backup hard disk drives that are a bit more expensive but they have been tested to run  24/7/365. They usually have a longer warranty than regular disks.

Well, good luck on this.

Comment: i was only thinking to connect it just with the usb cable or how is it done

Comment: I second NAS drives (WD Red, Seagate IronWolf). But they aren't "backup drives", they're meant to be frontline drives in a NAS array.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be used as a secondary HDD meant only to work with some specific data (website development).

As a general thought, I wouldn't expect this type of use to overly affect the long-term operation of the drive. That said, the longevity of any drive is almost certainly entirely dependent on the quality of its manufacturing.

Anecdotally, I had a very poorly made Seagate external hard drive, which I used daily, die in about 2 years (it was often *extremely* hot to the touch). In contrast, I also have some much better quality external Iomega drives (which stay relatively cool) that I use only less slightly than I did the Seagate and those have lasted for 5+ years now. So it's very likely a coin flip overall. =P

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that external (USB) enclosures have in general not very good cooling/heath dispersion.
This makes the harddisk inside it run hot and that can shorten the life-span greatly. This is normally not really a concern for a USB attached harddrives as most people won't have it running all the time. But it is something to think about if you use it on a permanent basis.

A metal enclosure is usually best, as metal conducts heat a lot better than plastic. And make sure there is some airflow around/over it.

A friend of mine learned this the hard way. When his internal harddrive ran full he started to use his USB backup-drive as a 2nd harddisk (just like you intend to do). The computer and that USB disk were placed under his desk in a closed cabinet with very little venting. 3 months later (using the computer several hours each day) the USB drive died, taking 3 months of work with it. (And obviously no backup, because he had re-purposed the backup-drive.)

2 additional points:

1. Go for USB3 or higher.
   USB2 will work but is a lot slower than a SATA internal harddrive. You won't like the speed difference between the internal and the external drive.
2. Configure Windows NOT to automatically manage the pagefile. Configure it manually to ONLY exist on the internal drive. USB was never designed to handle pagefile/swap memory operation across it.
   In some cases Windows (if left to auto-manage the pagefile) will put the pagefile (or one of the pagefiles) on the USB drive anyway. If that happens your system will sooner or later blue-screen, with a VERY HIGH chance that it happens in such a bad way that it corrupts the files on the USB drive.